# Reset Jquery mobile popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi i have a jQuery mobile popup with five buttons. based on the users click on a button some buttons are removed using `detach()` and new ones reappear using `$().html()`. -- then the user can either select a button or closes the popup. This essentially means the DOM of the popup is modified dynamically using JavaScript based on user clicks.

My question is once the popup is closed & the user reopens the popup he gets the modified popup not the original popup which i have in the static html code. Is there any way i can reset the popup to its original value without having to attach the html code back to the popup dynamically using popupbeforeposition event.

Like we can reload the same jqm page that brings the page to its original state...do we have something like a refresh or reload popup.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Store the original, restore it when it's closed. Where's your code?

Comment: Use `$( ".selector" ).on( "popupafterclose", function() {} );` to reset the popup.

Comment: @ F4r-20: Thanks where should i store it. how should i restore, do you mean adding back the html elements dynamically. My code is too big to be pasted here.. do you want me to create a fiddle for better understanding.

Comment: @Omar so is that the only way to do it. We dont use some reload or something to reset it.

Comment: Why don't you use Omar proposition plus load popup through jQuery load function? Of course you would also need to enhance its markup with popup('refresh').

Comment: @Gajotres- Yeah i was planning to do something like that...was just checking if there is some easier solution cause i use it at a number of places. Thanks anyways!

Comment: do you need a demo to clarify the idea?

Comment: Yes may be you can put it as an answer and i can mark it as the right one. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok I'll work on a demo for you.

Comment: Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2tDfE/

Comment: Thanks Omar ! Just a question why do you use popup twice: **$('#popup').popup().popup('open');**... This should do rite **$('#popup').popup('open');** Also can you put it as an answer so that i mark it as correct. Thanks again..